# Want only to resize middle view using auto layout

Tags: ios, autolayout, xcode6

I use autolayout in Xcode 6 to set up this nib. The only screen size that does not work well is 3.5".

This view is added as a subview to my main view controller's view.  The main view controller, before adding the subview, will change its view's frame height to match the 3.5" screen if it detects a 3.5" device.

I like the middle part - Collection View Background Image View & Collection View to adjust their heights, so that the top toolbar and bottom banner views & button are always visible on screen when shown on a 3.5" screen.  The Large White Activity Indicator will always be centred in the Collection view.

But when this view is shown on a 3.5" screen, the bottom banner views & button are not shown at all.  The bottom of the screen ends somewhere above the banner views.

I tried a lot of times playing around with the constraints and resistance priorities, but nothing worked.

What should I do to fix this?

Thanks in advance!

[image: view layout]

Answer (score 0):

I changed my way of implementation.  I use autolayout to set up the top toolbar and the bottom views.

I create the middle collection view background image and the collection view programmatically.  The height of the background image and the collection view are calculated by

```
CGFloat collectionViewBackgroundImageHeight = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height - _toolbarBackgroundImage.bounds.size.height - _aimBannerImageView.bounds.size.height;

CGFloat collectionViewHeight = collectionViewBackgroundImageHeight - 4;
```

Also, I add the following to make the xib matches the frame of its parent.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
     if (is3Point5InchScreen) {
          self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
     }
     [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
```